# Sum hours between 2 days

Tags: oracle

How to calculate hours between 2 days?

I have tried this :

```
ABS(TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AKHIR,'HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AWAL,'HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 AS SELISIH_JAM,
```

result :

```
| NO| JAM_AWAL    | JAM AKHIR    | SELISIH |
| 1 | 16.30    | 18.30        | 2      |
| 2 | 18.30    | 06.30        | 12      |
| 3 | 18.30    | 08.00        | 10.5      |    (WRONG)
```

but, NO 3 is wrong. 
and then I tried this :

```
CASE WHEN TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AWAL,'HH24:MI:SS') < TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AKHIR,'HH24:MI:SS')
     THEN                           
          ABS(TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AKHIR,'HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AWAL,'HH24:MI:SS')) *24

     WHEN TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AWAL,'HH24:MI:SS') > TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AKHIR,'HH24:MI:SS')
     THEN                           
          ABS(TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AWAL,'HH24:MI:SS') - TO_DATE(t11.JAM_AKHIR,'HH24:MI:SS')) *24                               
END SELISIH_JAM,
```

but still failed. please help me, thank you :)

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, from 08:00 to 18:30 **is** 10.5 hours (10 hours 30 minutes). What result do you expect? **EDIT** Aha, must be 13.5 hours. Well, try to use full date (date + time) while subtracting values, because now you got difference within the same day.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result. As is, it's hard to understand the types of your data and what you need to do.

Comment: The problem is that you are storing time component in a separate column as characters. I don't understand the need for this design. Why can't all be stored as one  date or timestamp column?

Comment: Can you have intervals with dates in more than 2 days? Also, is it possible to have an interval longer than 24 hours, even within 2 days?

Comment: Do you have a related date column as well (as an actual date or as a string), or only this 'time' column?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a day to the to_date of jam_akhir if it's greater than jam_awal, e.g.:

```
WITH your_table AS (SELECT 1 NO, '16.30' jam_awal, '18.30' jam_akhir FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 2 NO, '18.30' jam_awal, '06.30' jam_akhir FROM dual UNION ALL
                    SELECT 3 NO, '18.30' jam_awal, '08.00' jam_akhir FROM dual)
SELECT NO,
       jam_awal,
       jam_akhir,
       CASE WHEN to_date(jam_awal, 'hh24.mi') <= to_date(jam_akhir, 'hh24.mi')
                 THEN (to_date(jam_akhir, 'hh24.mi') - to_date(jam_awal, 'hh24.mi'))*24
            ELSE (to_date(jam_akhir, 'hh24.mi') + 1 - to_date(jam_awal, 'hh24.mi'))*24
       END selisih
FROM   your_table;

        NO JAM_AWAL JAM_AKHIR    SELISIH
---------- -------- --------- ----------
         1 16.30    18.30              2
         2 18.30    06.30             12
         3 18.30    08.00           13.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just the shorter alternative ;-)

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/XOL7482)</sup>**

```
select no, jam_akhir, jam_awal,
       mod (24 *(to_date(jam_akhir, 'hh24:mi') - to_date(jam_awal, 'hh24:mi') ) + 24, 24)
  from t11
```